# Unknown Item Label in R in Apriori

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am trying to filter rules which contain a certain category of item in the LHS , stored the items belonging to that category in the form of a vector and using this vector with subset to filter all the rules.

The error I am getting is "table contains an unknown item label".

Here's a snapshot of the code below:

top500vec is the vector which contains all the items of the same category ,interested at looking for rules with these items on the LHS side

[image]

Comment: Hi Jared, could you provide a sample of your data to make your question reproducible? This will increase the chance and speed to get a helpful answer. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

BY just looking at the error, it seems like `top500vec` contains item labels that are not defined in `top500onlyrules`. Check `itemLabels(top500onlyrules)` and make sure that `top500vec` only contains values that are valid item labels.

You should always post questions with reproducible examples. See: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I want the function to ignore labels that do not match in top500vec and top500onlyrules.

Comment: You need to remove these labels from top500vec first. You can probably do something like `filter_items <- intersect(as.character(top500vec), itemLabels(top500onlyrules))`.